# HTTP Browser Spoofing

Tags: http, telnet

How would i go about making a web server believe that i am using let's say Windows XP instead of Windows 7 via telnet?
I am thinking something along the lines of telneting to port 80 and issuing some commands but i am in doubt as to which.

Any help would be appreciated!

Jake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at User-Agent header in HTTP protocol. It allows you to specify the type of browser that's connecting. You can try to spoof that string and present yourself as a browser from different OS.